# Update Document reference for Internet Explorer using visual basics

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, vbscript

So I'm writing a script in Visual basics to fill out an online form. I'm able to fill out the first form, but after submitting it a new page opens and the internet explorer object is stuck on the previous page. I can only get it to work if I create a second ie object and redirect it to the 2nd page.

```
Dim coName As String
Dim usrName As String
Dim pwd As String

Dim wb As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

Set wb = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
wb.Visible = True
wb.Navigate("**********")
While wb.Busy
    Wait 0.100
Wend

wb.Document.getElementById("txt_CID").Value = "*****"
wb.Document.getElementById("txt_UID").Value = "*****"
wb.Document.getElementById("txt_PWD").Value = "*****"
wb.Document.getElementById("btnLogin").Click()
wb.Visible = True

Wait 2   (..............New Page loads here..............)

wb.Document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlTechID").Value = "IP3M-01"
```

the last line gives the error: "not an object reference" because the document loaded is still from the other page.

Is there a way to force ie.Document to update? I tried refreshing the page but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Do you absolutely have to use IE for this? If you can use another browser, I'd suggest writing a Greasemonkey script in JS instead. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey

Comment: yeah, sadly I have to use internet explorer

Comment: Does it refuse to load in anything other than IE? Is there no way to update or modify the web application? Does the vendor know the year is 2017 yet? :)